# Debugging Assembly Loading Failures without Admin rights

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

How can I debug assembly loading failures without Admin rights on the box?

I get the exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssemblyV2' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The default tool `fuslogvw` requires Admin rights to see the log.

Comment: you sure this is admin rights?  where is the assembly located?  perhaps the app you are loading has it's own assembly probing mechanism.  maybe you need to copy the assembly into the directory where the app you are debugging exists.

Comment: Don't know about the debugging, but 0x80131040 would hint that you want a different version of the assembly than what is found. But you might already know that and that's why you needed the debug info.

Comment: @TMcKeown, I am sure there is a technical issue causing this exception. I am pretty sure I could fix it by trial and error. But I would like something better than that. Regarding `fuslogvw`, I did try and the manual also says you need Admin rights.